# In PySpark, what is the difference between creating a DataFrame with or without Vectors.dense?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, vector, apache-spark-sql

I am creating 2 DataFrames, training and test, they both have a list in the feature column.
I show() both , and they all return the same structure. So i am wondering what is the difference and why the hassle with Vectors.dense?

```
training = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1.0, [0.0, 1.1, 0.1]),
        (0.0, [2.0, 1.0, -1.0]),
        (0.0, [2.0, 1.3, 1.0]),
        (1.0, [0.0, 1.2, -0.5]),
    ],
    ["label", "features"],
)

# Prepare test data
test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1.0, Vectors.dense([-1.0, 1.5, 1.3])),
        (0.0, Vectors.dense([3.0, 2.0, -0.1])),
        (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 2.2, -1.5])),
    ],
    ["label", "features"],
)

training.show()
test.show()
```

return:

```
+-----+----------------+
|label|        features|
+-----+----------------+
|  1.0| [0.0, 1.1, 0.1]|
|  0.0|[2.0, 1.0, -1.0]|
|  0.0| [2.0, 1.3, 1.0]|
|  1.0|[0.0, 1.2, -0.5]|
+-----+----------------+

+-----+--------------+
|label|      features|
+-----+--------------+
|  1.0|[-1.0,1.5,1.3]|
|  0.0|[3.0,2.0,-0.1]|
|  1.0|[0.0,2.2,-1.5]|
+-----+--------------+
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the answer myself, for ML model to work, this DataFrame needs an np.array here, not a list. My interpretation is, they are similar, but the structure is different.

Comments are totally welcome.